# Python comparison operators of wrong data type

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I am trying to allow the user to enter a column name from the DataFrame and comparison operator (`>=`, `<=`, or `==`) and based on the operator the user chooses, compare the DataFrame value to a closing value of their choice. The `df.loc[df[column_name]]` part and `valueofclose` part work fine, however I am getting an error:

```
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('float64'), dtype('<U2')) -> None
```

I believe the issue is because the user inputs a string and I need that to become source code, the only way I thought of doing it was using a + around it and adding the exec function, but that executes the code as well and I am not sure what to do after.

```
valueofclose = int(input("What is your value of the percent close: "))

column_name = input("Which column would you like to focus on: Percent Gain, Percent Loss or Day % Change: ")
operator = (input("What would you like for the operator to be: >=, <= or =="))

print(type(operator))

 df_loss = df.loc[df[column_name] + operator + valueofclose] #lets me find days where percent loss is greater than 4
for i, rows in df_loss.iterrows(): #Goes through the df_loss dataframe (where percent is greater than 4)
my_listloss = rows.notindex - 1 #and gets the index of that and subtracts the index by 1 to get the index of the next day
Percentloss_list.append(my_listloss) #adds that index to the list
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We can only tell you what is wrong with your code if you show us actual code. It doesn't have to be your whole project, but it does need to be a complete, self-contained example that shows the problem you're describing, that someone else can copy and paste and run. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for details. Also, [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: By the way, using the `exec` function with user-inputted strings is almost always a bad idea. The user can find ways to input malicious code, which would then be executed inside the program.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solution will help you:

```py
def add_op(a, b):
    return a + b

def power_op(a, b):
    return pow(a, b)

operation_dict = {
    '+': add_op,
    'power': power_op,
}

a, op, b = input("Enter command: ").split()
print(operation_dict[op](int(a), int(b)))
```

```
Enter command: 3 + 3
6

Enter command: 3 power 3
27
```

Or, in a simper code using `lambda`:

```py
operation_dict = {
    '+': lambda a, b: a + b,
    'power': lambda a, b: pow(a, b),
}

a, op, b = input("Enter command: ").split()
print(operation_dict[op](int(a), int(b)))
```

Comment: please consider adding comments and explanations too along with code.